# Error do not open links in a dropdown-menu

Tags: jquery

I have problems in clicking on the links from a dropdown-menu

By clicking on the link logout.php the dropdown-menu closes and does not open the link

I can not log out, because the dropdown-menu does not allow me to follow the link, how can I solve this problem?

My code jQuery dropdown-menu:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navigation li a').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if ($('#'+parent+' .Idropdown-menu').is (':hidden')) {
      $('.Idropdown-menu').hide();
      $('#'+parent+' .Idropdown-menu').show();
    } else {
      $('.Idropdown-menu').hide();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".Idropdown-menu").length === 0) {
      $(".Idropdown-menu").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

[Code execution https://jsfiddle.net/j30vd27o/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/j30vd27o/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the a click response and then returning false on every click. This is preventing your code from correctly following the link. You can probably rewrite it to be like this:

```
  $('.navigation li a').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if ($('#'+parent+' .Idropdown-menu').is (':hidden')) {
      $('.Idropdown-menu').hide();
      $('#'+parent+' .Idropdown-menu').show();
    return false;
    } else {
      $('.Idropdown-menu').hide();
      console.log("hiding")
    return true;
    }
  });
```

Also will your dropdown be full of href links that go to another page? If so you may be able to get ride of the else statement all together.

Comment: yes friend my menu will have several links to another page.